# How to redirect output to a file so the previous redirected output is not lost?

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm quite new to all this, trying to run a basic batch file to output some commands to a document.

It works fine until I add some more echos in.

Example:

```
echo "Failed Drives" > Report.rtf
symdisk list -failed >>Report.rtf
echo =====================================================>>Report.rtf

symcfg list -env_data -service_state failed >>Report.rtf
echo =====================================================>>Report.rtf

symcfg -thin -pool -GB list >>Report.rtf
echo =====================================================>>Report.rtf


explorer Report.rtf
```

So the above works fine, but if I want to add some more echos above each command to explain what the command does, it essentially ignores the previous command.

If above the `symcfg -thin -pool -GB list` command I add an `echo "Pool Capacity" > Report.rtf` it will ignore all of my previous script and just output that one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

> `command > filename`
> Redirect command output to a file
>
> `command >> filename`
> APPEND into a file

The link explains these operators for Windows CMD. I chose it because of the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag you used. In POSIX shell they are basically [the same](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02), so the answer applies to common shells in Unix/Linux as well.

In your original code all commands but first use `>>`. This makes sense. By using `>` in the middle you make your "extra" command *truncate* the file before writing to it.

It's not the previous commands are ignored. Their output is *overwritten* by your "extra" command.

Use `>>`.

Comment: Yep, that has done the trick, knew it would be something simple, thanks for the quick response and for the attached document

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to redirect everything at once:

```cmd
> "Report.rtf" (
    echo Failed Drives
    symdisk list -failed
    echo =====================================================

    symcfg list -env_data -service_state failed
    echo =====================================================

    echo Pool Capacity
    symcfg -thin -pool -GB list
    echo =====================================================
)
```

This is slightly faster due to a single file I/O operation, but this prevents you from reading the file before all redirected commands are completed.